# How do I add bookmark for starred sections without manually inserting pdfbookmark?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, subfiles

I have a large document with a mix of `\section*` and `\section`. I want all sections to appear in bookmarks. I am using `hyperref` and `bookmark` packages. I know that `\currentpdfbookmark` will do this but I don't want to edit the main file containing all the text since I am using `subfiles` to use same file for output in different layouts.

Comment: There is no simple switch for it. You will have to redefine \section*.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How do I do that?

Comment: A simple solution would be to define your own `\mysection`.  You'd still need to edit all the text, but then you could define the command to do what you want in the preface.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter
% store current section level
\xpretocmd\@startsection
  {\def\@currentseclevel{#2}}
  {}{\fail}

% add bookmark for \section*
\xapptocmd\H@old@ssect
  {\@addbookmark}
  {}{\fail}


\def\@addbookmark{%
  % after starred section, \@currentHref has form "section*.<num>"
  \expandafter\@add@bookmark\@currentHref\@nil
}


\def\@add@bookmark#1.#2\@nil{%
  \in@{*}{#1}%
  \ifin@
    % current section is a starred section
    \ifnum\@currentseclevel=1\relax
      % add bookmark for \section* only (level 1)
      \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\bookmark[dest=\@currentHref, level=\@currentseclevel]{\@currentlabelname}}%
      \@tempa
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Numbered section}
\section*{Starred section}

\subsection{Numbered subsection}
% \subsection* does not create bookmark
\subsection*{Starred subsection}

\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- `titlesec` package is not used since `hyperref` is not compatible with it, see the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), sec. 9.1.38.
- The above code can be adjusted to add bookmarks for sectioning commands lower than `\section*`, e.g., `\subsection*` and `\subsubsection*`.
- Once the `\section*` creates a bookmark, following (numbered) `\subsection` will create a bookmark under the bookmark for `\section*`.

Comment: Nice suggestion `+1`